# Measuring performance degradation between performance between runs

Tags: python, locust

I wondered if there is a standard way in locust to detect and warn about performance degradation between runs. E.g.

Suppose I have an endpoint `GET /helloworld` that returns a json like:

`{"message":"hello world"}`
on run1 of the performance test suite, the response time was 1 second, but running the `locust` command, now returns in 3 secs. In my contrived example, lets say 3 secs is an 'acceptable' response time, thus we don't want to fail the test. However, the performance of the endpoint has degraded and we want to warn about this. What is the best way to achieve this in locust?

I thought maybe to save the results in `csv` after each run and do a comparison with the `csv` produced by the current/last run, but is there an easier way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more advanced comparison/tracking options you might want to look at Locust Dashboards/Timescale  https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/tree/master/locust_plugins/timescale

While it doesnt have any built-in signal for performance degradations, it does have a nice graph for runs over time, and enables after-the-fact analysis.

Comment: What's the best way to do this in CI/CD where you don't have a GUI and just want to save, perhaps the csv into some backend database that can be queried?

Comment: For CI/CD I use the --check-avg-response-time and --check-rps parameters. If the checks fail, I manually look at the timescale graphs to see any trends.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe locust-plugins’s `—check-avg-response-time` fits your need? It logs a message and changes Locust’s process exit code.

Used like this:

`locust -f locustfile_that_imports_locust_plugins.py --check-avg-response-time 50`

https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/9a4eb77ac4581871db951b454631dc6c49fa1c7a/examples/cmd_line_examples.sh#L6

Comment: Thank you, but does it? As far as I can tell it checks the average response time of a particular run. I would want to take that and compare it to the average response time the previous time was locust was run and compare the run times to check for a performance degradation between locust runs. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how big is your project and how much data you need to evaluate.

We are using keptn for such purpose (https://keptn.sh/)

If you will deploy it, prepare SLI/SLO files you can integrate Locust with Keptn. Once load test is finished evaluation is triggered for given data.

In our case Jenkins build is set to Pass/Warn/Fail state depending on the evaluation outcome.

There are rules that can compare data for last X samples.
Eventually, you need to gather 100 points to have Green build

On degradation you will have less points causing failure.

[Score graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ4Dt.png)

[Latency graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zcoa.png)